# Is it possible to pass authorized scope 'groups' to an Azure Enterprise OIDC app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

**Problem:** I am trying to configure my Azure Enterprise OIDC(Azure AD) application to allow me to pass 'groups' as scope(along with 'openid email'). However, currently I am only able to get groups if I pass scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/GroupMember.Read.All`.

**Question:** Is it possible to configure the enterprise application to request the group scope as `groups` and not as `https://graph.microsoft.com/GroupMember.Read.All`? Additionally, is it possible to return the group names rather than the ID's of the groups?

**Working configuration:**

**Authorize URI:** [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)

**Scopes:** openid email https://graph.microsoft.com/GroupMember.Read.All

**Enterprise Application:** Microsoft Entra Gallery -> AWS Single-Account Access

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `Group.Read.All` scope instead of `GroupMember.Read.All`.

With `Group.Read.All`, you can read groups and memberships.